# Kendo MVC dropdown - blank space when option label remove

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

When user selects any option on kendo's dropdown I'm removing option label. In some of dropdowns there is white/blank space instead of removed option label. It looks like:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Q9L.png)

Dropdown code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("apps")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .OptionLabel("Please select a software")
    .BindTo(Model.Apps)
    .Events(e => {
        e.Close("onCloseDropdown");
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "ddApps", style = "width: 30%" })
)
```

onCloseDropdown:

```
function onCloseDropdown() {
    var val = $('#ddApps').val();

    if (val !== "") {
        this.element.getKendoDropDownList().list.find('.k-list-optionlabel').remove();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
    (...)
}
```

I noticed that problem doesn't appears when there are no many options and scroll is disabled.
When I have a lot of options and scroll is enabled, I guess kendo needs to resize somehow to fix the height after remove the option label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hiding the option label entry rather than removing it - like so:

```
function onCloseDropdown() {
    var val = $('#ddApps').val();

    if (val !== "") {
        this.element.getKendoDropDownList().list.find(".k-list-optionlabel").hide();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Also, depending on your use cases, since you only remove the option label on close of the drop down, if you have a view where the drop down is populated with a selection on load it would still have the option label. If you don't want that you could call the same hide option label code from the dataBound event

EDIT:

Another option would be to do your remove code like you have, but then refresh the dropdown after like so:

```
function onCloseDropdown() {
    var val = $('#ddApps').val();

    if (val !== "") {
        this.element.getKendoDropDownList().list.find('.k-list-optionlabel').remove();
        this.element.getKendoDropDownList().refresh();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work properly, I edited main post with my insight

Comment: I updated with another option to call refresh after your call to remove

Comment: Great! I was trying with ```kendo.resize($('#id'))```, but your refresh resolved problem, thanks ;)